# Python pandas: Best way to normalize data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, normalization

I have a large pandas dataframe with about 80 columns. Each of the 80 columns in the dataframe report daily traffic statistics for websites (the columns are the websites).

As I don't want to work with the raw traffic statistics, I rather like to normalize all of my columns (except for the first, which is the date). Either from 0 to 1 or (even better) from 0 to 100.

```
Date        A      B      ...
10/10/2010  100.0  402.0  ...
11/10/2010  250.0  800.0  ...
12/10/2010  800.0  2000.0 ...
13/10/2010  400.0  1800.0 ...
```

That being said, I wonder which normalization to apply. [Min-Max scaling](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html) vs. z-Score Normalization (standardization)? Some of my columns have strong outliers. It would be great to have an example. I am sorry not being able to provide the full data.

Answer (score 17):

First, turn your Date column into an index.

```
dates = df.pop('Date')
df.index = dates
```

Then either use z-score normalizing:

```
df1 = (df - df.mean())/df.std()
```

or min-max scaling:

```
df2 = (df-df.min())/(df.max()-df.min())
```

I would probably advise z-score normalization, because min-max scaling is highly susceptible to outliers.

Comment: In the case that the outliers are little too strong for my perception, would you recommend min-max then?

Comment: Also, I tried this. Unfortunately, the values are not between 0 and 1 or 0 and 1 but ranging from -3 to 1? There should be decimals, too?

Comment: If you have any strong outliers and you don't want to remove them from the data set prior to analysis, then I would recommend that you do z-score normalization.

Comment: I think you might have been getting errors because I was destroying the old copy of df every time I did a command. I slightly modified it to make it more straightforward.

Comment: After running the code, then run df1.describe() and df2.describe(). df1.describe() should tell you that the mean of each column is zero and the std of each column is 1. df2.describe() should tell you that the min of each column is zero and the max of each column is 1.